# What is the difference between an adjective when it ends with an E and when it doesn't?

Tags: adjective, german-to-english, adjective-ending

- menschenähnlich
- menschenähnliche

What is the difference if translated to English?

Comment: The system of the German adjective declensions is a bit complicated. And therefore it is a grammar chapter to study. It is not a matter of asking what is the difference between an adjective without ending and with the ending -e.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning is the same -- only the usage is different.

**Menschenähnlich** is the predicative form of the adjective. It modifies the subject of the sentence and follows a linking verb.

> Das Verhalten von Affen ist menschenähnlich.
>
> The behaviour of apes is manlike.

**Menschenähnliche** is the attributive form of the adjective. It modifies the noun directly.

> Die Studien zeigen ein menschenähnliches Verhalten von Affen.
>
> The studies show a manlike behaviour of apes.

The ending of an attributive adjective depends on the case and gender of the corresponding noun.

Comment: not to forget the preceding article. It depends on that, too.